# Electron.build auto-updater - when does it download updates?

Tags: electron, auto-update

I've managed to successfully implement the auto-update feature for Windows and Mac for my application using https://www.electron.build/auto-update.

I wonder whether the download continues when the users closes the application (and, obviously, an update has been found)? Or does the application need to stay open until the the update has been completely downloaded?

Comment: The application needs to be open for the download to complete

Comment: @Ajey Thank you. Could you provide a link or some documentation (out of curiosity)? I would accept your answer, if you could add it as an answer instead of a comment. ;-)